# Bad Smooth Scrolling on Vue JS 2 + A-Frame

Tags: vuejs2, aframe, smooth-scrolling

I implemented an A-Frame animation inside a single section on a Vue Js 2 webapp project.
I also added a smooth scrolling component for the global app. My A-Frame block is set to "embedded" to not take the the full screen size.

On Development everything looks nice. When I go live my smooth scrolling is really bad espacially on mobile device. I looked to disable A-Frame on mobile device but no info on the doc, I tried to do it with css with media queries but still the same issue.

I don't know from where it comes and which part of code I have to fix. No error on the console.

Anyone met this kind of issue please?!
Thx

Comment: check if aframe is supported by the browser version you are using

Answer (score 0):

I've not run into this issue before, but you could try to place the aframe scene in a separate file, then use an iframe in your main page and see if it improves.

Comment: Hi Noam, thank you for your time. Actually Vue Js is based on separated and reusable components so my A-frame is already on a separate file/component and I'm calling where I need to display it.